# Application name is displayed as java instead of "my application" name in Mac-Sonoma beta version

Tags: java, macos, swing, jframe

[image]
Am using Java swing (Jframe) application, where it is showing java as its name in menu bar after upgrading to Sonoma beta 2 version how do I fix it, it’s a sample Jframe application used for testing.please advice me some workaround if any one had faced the same issue

```
  

import javax.swing.*;

class SwingDemo {
    SwingDemo() {
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame(" A simple applicattion");
        jfrm.setSize(275, 100);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel jlab = new JLabel(" Swing means powerful GUIs.");
        jfrm.add(jlab);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("apple.awt.application.name", "MMscheduling");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SwingDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: use `jpackage` to get native launcher (`--type app-image`). you shouldn't have this problem with it.